# Ошибка list index out of range при переносе последнего элемента из каждого списка в двумерном массиве

Tags: python, python-3.x

Из столбца Name csv файла беру значения, разбиваю каждое на список символов и загружаю в массив arr.
Затем мне нужно заполнить массив words последним элементом из каждого списка двумерного массива arr, но вылетает ошибка list index out of range.

```
import csv 

arr = []
words = []
i = 0

with open(r'C:\Users\Hard_PC\Documents\table.csv', newline = '', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        arr.append(list(row['Name']))
while i < len(arr):
    words.append(arr[i][-1])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Создайте, пожалуйста, [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Заполните `arr` прямо в коде минимальной частью данных, на которых воспроизводится проблема, оставьте только цикл. Уберите чтение из файла (эта часть же хорошо работает, на суть вопроса она не влияет).

Comment: Есть хорошая функция - print(). Она позволяет узнать, действительно ли в arr лежит то, что вы думаете.

Comment: Да, я пробовал функцию print(), в arr действительно то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
arr.append(list(row['Name']))
```

должно быть только

```
arr.append(row['Name'])
```

потому что функция `list()` сделает из строки *список её букв.*